# Show the data from the main class on another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, output

I'm making a simple Grading system by using a GUI developed through Eclipse. How should I output the `average` and `Name` on another JFrame?

I want to move the calculated average from the first JFrame to the second JFrame, and I also want to output a message on the second JFrame saying:

```
"Hi," + the name entered + your average grade is: .
```

So basically the output on the second JFrame would be something like this:

```
Hi Bahramdun Adil! Your Average is: 99%
```

You can run the code that I created to help you understand.

Here's the code:     `package gradesystem;

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextArea;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Frame1 {

    public JFrame frame;
    public JTextField textField;
    public JTextField prelim;
    public JTextField midterm;
    public JTextField prefinal;
    public JTextField pinal;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 495, 311);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        textField.setBounds(136, 58, 256, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter Name");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(25, 60, 101, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblEnterPrelimGrade = new JLabel("Enter Prelim Grade");
        lblEnterPrelimGrade.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblEnterPrelimGrade.setBounds(25, 119, 101, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterPrelimGrade);

        prelim = new JTextField();
        prelim.setColumns(10);
        prelim.setBounds(136, 117, 55, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(prelim);

        midterm = new JTextField();
        midterm.setColumns(10);
        midterm.setBounds(136, 148, 55, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(midterm);

        prefinal = new JTextField();
        prefinal.setColumns(10);
        prefinal.setBounds(136, 179, 55, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(prefinal);

        pinal = new JTextField();
        pinal.setColumns(10);
        pinal.setBounds(136, 210, 55, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pinal);

        JLabel lblEnterMidtermGrade = new JLabel("Enter Midterm Grade");
        lblEnterMidtermGrade.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblEnterMidtermGrade.setBounds(25, 150, 101, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterMidtermGrade);

        JLabel lblEnterPrefinalGrade = new JLabel("Enter Pre-final Grade");
        lblEnterPrefinalGrade.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblEnterPrefinalGrade.setBounds(25, 181, 101, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterPrefinalGrade);

        JLabel lblEnterFinalGrade = new JLabel("Enter Final Grade");
        lblEnterFinalGrade.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblEnterFinalGrade.setBounds(25, 212, 101, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterFinalGrade);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("20%");
        label.setBounds(198, 119, 31, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("20%");
        label_1.setBounds(198, 150, 31, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_1);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("20%");
        label_2.setBounds(198, 181, 31, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_2);

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("40%");
        label_3.setBounds(198, 212, 31, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_3);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Click to get total Average!");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {



                int first;
                int second;
                int third;
                int fourth;
                double grade;

                first=Integer.parseInt(prelim.getText());
                second=Integer.parseInt(midterm.getText());
                third=Integer.parseInt(prefinal.getText());
                fourth=Integer.parseInt(pinal.getText());

                grade=first*.2+second*.2+third*.2+fourth*.4;                                                
                NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                String grado=formatter.format(grade);   
                Frame2 s2= new Frame2();
                JTextField lblgrade = new JTextField(grado);
                lblgrade.setEditable(false);
                lblgrade.setBounds(302, 204, 30, 26);
                frame.getContentPane().add(lblgrade);
                lblgrade.setColumns(10);




            }

        });

        btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(255, 119, 184, 51);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("GRADING SYSTEM");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(26, 11, 397, 36);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel lblAverage = new JLabel("Average:");
        lblAverage.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblAverage.setBounds(293, 182, 80, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAverage);

        JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("%");
        label_4.setBounds(342, 210, 27, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label_4);
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not clear about what you want to do with your second `JFrame`, but you want to open a second `JFrame` which in this case the `Frame1` as in your example code, then you add the below exactly where you want to open the second `JFrame`

```
private static void luanch() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Call this method in your main `method`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    luanch();
}
```

And also in where you want to open the second `JFrame`

```
grade=first*.2+second*.2+third*.2+fourth*.4;                                                
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String grado=formatter.format(grade);   
//Frame2 s2= new Frame2();

luanch(); // here

JTextField lblgrade = new JTextField(grado);
```

**Note:** If you want to just show the message, then you ca use message dialog as below:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hi! "+textField.getText()+" Your average is "+grado+"%");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try it. =)

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. So basically what I want to do is when I click the Jbutton on the first frame it would open a second frame and out put the total average and the message. Again, I'm sorry if I was not that clear.

Comment: That OK no problem, I have updated the answer you can see

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much Bahramdun Adil!! It solved my problem. ^_^